# Spring FirestoreReactiveRepository custom query is not working - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-repositories

I am trying to build some custom queries like the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/2.0.4/reference/html/index.html#reactive-repositories) is saying, but it is not working.

I got stuck in what i think is the block method and not any data is retrieved.

Here is my repo class:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<User> {

    Flux<User> findByCPF(String CPF);
    Flux<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

and here is the model:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collectionName = "userCollection")
public class User extends BaseEntity {


    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.name}")
    private String name;

    @Email
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.email}")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.password}")
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.address}")
    private String address;

    @CPF
    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.cpf}")
    private String CPF;

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.birthDate}")
    private Date birthDate;

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.notnull.user.role}")
    private UserRoleEnum role;
}
```

this is the method that i'm building that i get stuck:

```java
    @Override
    public Mono<User> create(User entity) {
        var cpf = userRepository.findByCPF(entity.getCPF());
        var email =  userRepository.findByEmail(entity.getEmail());
        
        if(cpf == null || email == null)
           throw new EntityExistException();
       else
        return super.create(entity);
    }
```

Yeah, it's an override because i have a generic service class:

```java
public class GenericService<T>{

    private FirestoreReactiveRepository<T> firestoreReactiveRepository;

    public GenericService(FirestoreReactiveRepository<T> firestoreReactiveRepository){
        this.firestoreReactiveRepository = firestoreReactiveRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Mono<T> create(T entity){
        return firestoreReactiveRepository.save(entity);
    }

**** HIDED CONTENT *****
```

Do you know how custom queries can be built with this FirestoreReactiveRepository ?

Comment: Can you post the full subclass that extends your `GenericService<User>`? Also any error stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Of what types are:

```java
var cpf = userRepository.findByCPF(entity.getCPF());
var email = userRepository.findByEmail(entity.getEmail());
```

?

You can write them also like:

```java
Flux<User> cpf = userRepository.findByCPF(entity.getCPF());
Flux<User> email = userRepository.findByEmail(entity.getEmail());
```

I see three problems:

1. You don't subscribe to the `cpf` and `email` fluxes
2. The condition inside if is always false because both fluxes are not null

```java
 if(cpf == null || email == null)
```

3. ... assuming that `cpf` and `email` would not be `Flux<User>` but `User` I think the condition should be `cpf != null || email != null`

The code could look more like this:

```java
    @Override
    public Mono<User> create(User entity) {
        var cpf = userRepository.findByCPF(entity.getCPF()); // Flux<User> cpf = ...
        var email = userRepository.findByEmail(entity.getEmail()); // Flux<User> email = ...

        return cpf.mergeWith(email)
                .<User>handle((user, sink) -> sink.error(new EntityExistException()))
                .switchIfEmpty(super.create(entity))
                .next();
    }
```